# Qt 5.5.0 with mingw on Windows : Compiled executable can't be terminated

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator, mingw32

I have a really weird problem here.
I am using **Qt 5.5.0** with **mingw 4.9.2 32bit** and QtCreator and Git on Windows 7.

My Project builds just fine but when I run the executable either outside or inside QtCreator the process appears in Task-Manager/ProcessExplorer but **the Window itself does not show** up and when I try to kill the process it does not react. Process Hacker can't terminate the process either. The QtCreator debugger waits in vain for the process to start. I have to reboot the PC to kill the process.

Thing is that it worked a few days ago and other qt projects work fine, too. I had the same issue on a different PC. I couldn't find the issue so I reset it to stock; I can't do the same with this one.

What could I have possibly done to cause this?

Comment: Process Explorer and Process Hacker can show stack traces of the threads, can you post them here? Also, you may try to run that binary under Process Monitor and look at what resources it is trying to use before becoming stuck. And try to update to 5.5.1, 5.5.0 had a lot of bugs.

Comment: It needs debug? Press Interrupt || in Qt Creator debugger and go through threads, see why they hang. I suspect main thread being hanged up.

Comment: "Thing is that it worked a few days ago” - did you change your dev environment, or your project, or both? If only the project changed, I’d go through the version control history to find the regression (e.g. git bisect if you use git). Otherwise, use a debugger.

Comment: @Paul I'd like to give you the stack traces and procmon data but I can't. ProcessExplorer has an error when accessing the thread and ProcessHacker never finishes. I'll try updating to 5.5.1 but that didn't work on the other machine either.

Comment: @FrankOsterfield The Project works fine on my other machine. It's likely that it has something to do with the way the project is configured but I deleted all configurations and the error persisted.

Comment: @AlexanderVX The Debugger has no control over the program becaus it doesn't respond so I can't just pause it.

Comment: The Debugger should always be able to stop the program. That means you have not properly configured the debugger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028015/how-add-a-debug-to-a-kit-in-qt-for-msvc2013/34028671#34028671

Comment: And make sure you start the program with Start Debugging not Run in Qt Creator.

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of antivirus or other similar software installed on the machine that hooks the process creation and for some reason prevents the process from running. At least the symptoms are that something is wrong at the kernel level.

Comment: @Paul oh my god, I can't believe it was the antivirus. Isn't an antivirus supposed to tell me if it blocks, or analyzes something? Because it didn't show me ANYTHING. Thank you, Paul!

Comment: So it actually was the antivirus after all?

Comment: yes, it was the antivirus (>ლ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the issue. **It was my antivirus software**. I am using avast free antivirus and somehow it caused the issue without telling me. Excluding the build directory from the scans solved the issue.

Thanks to Paul for the answer!